# Load javascript based on clicked item

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I have three widgets in my project directory and wants to display all three widgets in same html page based on the click. For eg, I have three DOM elements Widget A, Widget B,Widget C. **Based on the click event I have to load these widgets**, if we click on Widget A, the first widget should load likewise if we click on Widget B, the second widget should load and so on.  Separate scripts are there for each widget. There is a result and error handling method is also there for each widgets.

My Project Structure

```
Widgets Folder
|--index.html
|--lst/lst.js
|--loc/loc.js
|--ret/ret.js
```

This is my HTML Code

```
<div id="WIDGETA"></div>
<div id="WIDGETB"></div>
<div id="WIDGETC"></div>


<div id="a"><span>Widget A</span></div>
<div id="b"><span>Widget B</span></div>
<div id="c"><span>Widget C</span></div>
```

And the Javascript

```
<script>

        var selection;
        document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click",function(){
            alert("first widget");
            selection = "lst";
        });

        document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click",function(){
            alert("second widget");
            selection = "loc"; 
        });

        document.getElementById("c").addEventListener("click",function(){
            alert("third widget");
            selection = "ret"; 
        });

        (function(window, document) {
            var loader = function() {
                var script = document.createElement("script"),
                tag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                var lstScript = "lst/lst.js";
                var locScript = "loc/loc.js";
                var retScript = "ret/ret.js";
                switch(selection){
                    case "lst" :       script.src = lstScript;                                         
                                        break;
                    case "location" :   script.src = locScript;                                         
                                        break;   
                    case "return" :     script.src = retScript;                                         
                                        break;    
                }

                function handleError() {
                    var errorMsg = "Ooops, Widget failed to load. :(";
                    var errorEvent = new CustomEvent('widgetErrorHandler', {
                        'detail': errorMsg
                    });
                    document.getElementById("WIDGETA").dispatchEvent(errorEvent);
                    document.getElementById("WIDGETB").dispatchEvent(errorEvent);
                    document.getElementById("WIDGETC").dispatchEvent(errorEvent);
                }
                script.async = true;
                tag.parentNode.insertBefore(script, tag);
            };
            window.location_options = {
                lst_widget_open_ref_id: '#WIDGETA',
                loc_widget_open_ref_id: '#WIDGETB',
                ret_widget_open_ref_id: '#WIDGETC'
            };
            window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener("load", loader, false) : window.attachEvent("onload", loader);

        })(window, document);
        // result handling WidgetA
        document.getElementById("WIDGETA").addEventListener('store', function(e) {
            alert("Got result from Widget - A");
        }, false);
        // error handling WidgetA
        document.getElementById("WIDGETA").addEventListener('widgetErrorHandler', function(e) {
            alert("Error loading Widget - A");
        }, false);

        // result handling WidgetB
        document.getElementById("WIDGETB").addEventListener('store', function(e) {
            alert("Got result from Widget - A");
        }, false);
        // error handling WidgetB
        document.getElementById("WIDGETB").addEventListener('widgetErrorHandler', function(e) {
            alert("Error loading Widget - A");
        }, false);

        // result handling WidgetC
        document.getElementById("WIDGETC").addEventListener('store', function(e) {
            alert("Got result from Widget - A");
        }, false);
        // error handling WidgetC
        document.getElementById("WIDGETC").addEventListener('widgetErrorHandler', function(e) {
            alert("Error loading Widget - A");
        }, false);
    </script>
```

For a single widget, the script is working fine and loading the widget successfully (need to remove the `selection` logic ). But when I add multiple widgets, it is not loading the scripts/widgets. I don't have the permission to remove the `function(window, document){}` function. Is there any way to achieve the task with less modification in the above skeleton.

Comment: From the description you have given, it is difficult to make out where you are stuck. Can you explain the same?

Comment: updated the question. Basically this is my requirement - based on the clicked elements, I need to load the widget scripts.

Comment: Requirement is understood, but where are you stuck? Do you get any error right now when you try to load other scripts?

Comment: Scripts are not loading when I click.

Comment: Can you refactor the loader method inside the self-invoking `(function(window, document) {` so that they can be invoked on the click event of `div a,b,c`?

Answer (score 1):

I can propose this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="WIDGETA"></div>
<div id="WIDGETB"></div>
<div id="WIDGETC"></div>


    <div id="a"><span>Widget A</span></div>
    <div id="b"><span>Widget B</span></div>
    <div id="c"><span>Widget C</span></div>
<script>

        var selection;

        (function(window, document) {
            var loader = function() {
                var script = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                if (script['async']) {
                    script.remove();
                }
                script = document.createElement("script");
                tag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                var lstScript = "lst/lst.js";
                var locScript = "loc/loc.js";
                var retScript = "ret/ret.js";
                switch(selection){
                    case "lst" :       
                        script.src = lstScript;
                        break;
                    case "loc" :   
                        script.src = locScript;       
                        break;   
                    case "ret" :     
                        script.src = retScript;      
                        break;    
                }

                function handleError() {
                    var errorMsg = "Ooops, Widget failed to load. :(";
                    var errorEvent = new CustomEvent('widgetErrorHandler', {
                        'detail': errorMsg
                    });
                    document.getElementById("WIDGETA").dispatchEvent(errorEvent);
                    document.getElementById("WIDGETB").dispatchEvent(errorEvent);
                    document.getElementById("WIDGETC").dispatchEvent(errorEvent);
                }
                script.async = true;
                tag.parentNode.insertBefore(script, tag);
            };
            window.location_options = {
                lst_widget_open_ref_id: '#WIDGETA',
                loc_widget_open_ref_id: '#WIDGETB',
                ret_widget_open_ref_id: '#WIDGETC'
            };
            var addEvent = function (o, fn) {
                o.addEventListener ? o.addEventListener("click", fn, false) : o.attachEvent("onclick", fn);
            }
            addEvent(document.getElementById("a"), function(){
                //alert("first widget");
                selection = "lst";
                loader();
            });
            addEvent(document.getElementById("b"),function(){
                //alert("second widget");
                selection = "loc"; 
                loader();
            });
            addEvent(document.getElementById("c"),function(){
                //alert("third widget");
                selection = "ret"; 
                loader();
            });

        })(window, document);
        // result handling WidgetA
        document.getElementById("WIDGETA").addEventListener('store', function(e) {
            alert("Got result from Widget - A");
        }, false);
        // error handling WidgetA
        document.getElementById("WIDGETA").addEventListener('widgetErrorHandler', function(e) {
            alert("Error loading Widget - A");
        }, false);

        // result handling WidgetB
        document.getElementById("WIDGETB").addEventListener('store', function(e) {
            alert("Got result from Widget - A");
        }, false);
        // error handling WidgetB
        document.getElementById("WIDGETB").addEventListener('widgetErrorHandler', function(e) {
            alert("Error loading Widget - A");
        }, false);

        // result handling WidgetC
        document.getElementById("WIDGETC").addEventListener('store', function(e) {
            alert("Got result from Widget - A");
        }, false);
        // error handling WidgetC
        document.getElementById("WIDGETC").addEventListener('widgetErrorHandler', function(e) {
            alert("Error loading Widget - A");
        }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It attaches the appropriate script tags based on the click, but the widget is not showing.

Comment: I can't help you, nobody can, we don't have the widget code;

Comment: Hi, The widget is loading successfully now. Found that it is taking some time to load the js files. on the first click it is not opening but if we click on second time, it is loading. How can I load the whole thing in a single click or wait till the script loads completely.